# Extract values from key-value pair and output values alone separated by comma

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Input file data

```
Name: aa
Age: 20
Address: zzzz

Name: bb
Age: 17
Address: cccc
```

I want to output like this

```
aa,20,zzzz
bb,17,cccc
```

Comment: welcome @Yumiko to Unix Stack overflow, to help us help you, please add a sample of your input file, I will try to edit your question based on my understandings, feel free to add your touch.

Comment: @Eng7 that is an example of the input file ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
Name: aa
Age: 20
Address: zzzz

Name: bb
Age: 17
Address: cccc

$ awk 'NF{print $2}' ip.txt | pr -3ats,
aa,20,zzzz
bb,17,cccc
```

- Using `awk` to print only second column values and skip empty lines by checking `NF`
- Then use `pr` to print in 3 columns with `,` as separator

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -00nE 'say join(",", /:\s*(.*)/g)' ip.txt
```

where:

- `perl -00nE EXP` - stands for: foreach paragraph do {EXP}
- `/:(.*)/g`  - returns the list of the matching groups
- `join(",", list)` - separate the elements by `,`

\thanks{Sundeep}

Comment: good one, can use `/:\s*(.*)/g` to account for optional spaces between key-value pairs

Answer (score 1):

An example using Perl. Iterate over each line in the file, and capture just the data we want into an array, then join the elements of the array with a comma and print it.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'file.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

while (my $line = <$fh>){
    my @sections = $line =~ /:\s(.*?)\s/g;
    print join ',', @sections;
    print "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
aa,20,zzzz
bb,17,cccc
```